# Invalid request BLR at offset 951

Tags: firebird, database-migration, interbase

I have got gdb files (25GB another ~38 GB) which were created by Firebird 1.0.
During opening some of the tables they show error [running Firebird Server 1.0 (stopped Interbase 7.5)]-> Invalid request BLR at offset 951
what does it mean ?

In addition I'd like to convert it to Interbase 7.5 It has ODS ver. 10 (via gstat -h).

Any ideas ??

Comment: What is the full error? Usually there is an additional line that includes the actual thing that is invalid.

Comment: It has disappeared ! I copied ib udf written dll to firebird folder and now it's OK!

Comment: Then most likely the additional error was `function <name of UDF function> is not defined module name or entrypoint could not be found`

Answer (score 5):

First of all try to check a database for corruption and possibly mend it:

```
gfix -mend -full -ignore -user SYSDBA -pas masterkey database.gdb
```

If there are errors reported then do backup-restore cycle:

```
gbak -b -ig -g -user SYSDBA -pas masterkey server:database.gdb database.gbk

gbak -c -user SYSDBA -pas masterkey database.gbk server:new.gdb
```

If restore fails then you need to do restore with indexes being deactivated and activate them later one by one:

```
gbak -c -i -n -o -user SYSDBA -pas masterkey database.gbk server:new.gdb
```

I believe that Firebird 1.0 is an enhanced Interbase 6.0. So, there is a chance that backup of FB 1.0 would be restored using IB 7.5. If no, then you always has a solution of dumping database into sql INSERT commands.

Answer (score 0):

About converting to Interbase - the Firebird 1.0 ODS should be basically the same as the Interbase of that time, so you might be able to create backup under FB and restaore it under IB 7.5 . If that doesn't work out you have to create new empty database in IB and then "pump" the data from FB to IB using [Clever Component's Interbase DataPump](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/datapump/index.asp) or some other similar tool. Given the size of the DB it is going to be a long wait in either way...

Sorry, no idea about the error - it might indicate that the DB / some table is corrupted or just that you have used IB to change the metadata of the DB and now FB doesn't understand those changes (as the IB7.5 BLR is probably not compatible with FB1.0).